# Watir webdriver; counting elements with changing class names

Tags: ruby, rspec, count, watir-webdriver

I am using Rspec and Watir-webdriver and am looking to get a count of all the elements that have been clicked.

What I'm doing:

I perform a search and get back a list of results; I then run a loop to select only 5 of them.  The class name for these elements goes from `asset-card selectable` to now saying `asset-card selectable selected`.

I try to get a proper count by doing this:

```
count = @browser.elements(:class, 'selected').size
```

But this is still giving me *all* results and not specifically the ones that now have `selected` as part of the class name.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this? 
 This is what the html looks like:

```
<div class="search results">
    <div class="asset-card selectable selected"></div>
    <div class="asset-card selectable selected"></div>
    <div class="asset-card selectable"></div>
    <div class="asset-card selectable"></div>
    <div class="asset-card selectable"></div>
</div>
```

In this html example, the first two elements have been selected

Comment: Are you saying that `@browser.elements(:class, 'selected')` returns elements with a class of `asset-card selectable`?  If you can provide the HTML in question, that would help in reproducing your issue.

Comment: @orde, I have updated my original post to show what the HTML is doing

Comment: @kmancusi, are you saying that `@browser.elements(:class, 'selected').size` does not return "2" for the sample HTML?

Comment: @JustinKo: yes, this is initially the issue I was running into--coincidentally I resolved this just now -_-

Answer (score 0):

I feel rather dumb; I found a solution that fixes the issue of *why* I wasn't getting a proper count returned: it's because I wasn't waiting long enough

After I placed a `sleep 1` duration, it returned a count accurate to what I was clicking on.  My thought on this isn't exactly technical, but it was acting as if the click action and class name change was performing actions before a proper count could be determined. 
  I will be looking to place a more elegant `wait` solution as I'd like to avoid having to use `sleep` commands if possible