# Locating elements without a specific class name

Tags: rspec, watir, watir-webdriver, class-names

This is in the same vein as this question I asked before - [Watir webdriver; counting elements with changing class names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37492341/4190664). I was able to add the specific number of elements based on using the class name `asset-card selectable`.

Currently, I am looking to click on more elements to *add* them to the existing set.  Here is my dilemma:

- When an element *is not* clicked, the class name is: 
   `image-card asset-card selectable`
- When an element is clicked, `selected` is appended to the class name: 
   `image-card asset-card selectable selected`

In my case, I am trying to look for additional elements that *only* say `image-card asset-card selectable` and do not include `selected`. I am not sure how to explicitly locate them.

Is there a regex solution or any other thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to find an element without a certain class is to use a `:css` locator.

```
browser.divs(css: 'div.image-card.asset-card.selectable:not(.selected)')
```

An explanation of the CSS-selectors:

- `div` - This is the tag name of the elements you are trying to match
- `.image-card.asset-card.selectable` - This is the list of classes you want the matching elements to have
- `:not(.selected)` - This is the list of classes you *do not* want the matching elements to have

If you are opposed to CSS-selectors, you could iterate over the elements. Note that this will be slower as it has to make more calls to the browser.

```
selectable = browser.divs(class: 'image-card asset-card selectable')
unselected = selectable.reject { |e| e.class_name.split(' ').include?('selected') }
```

I have tried to use a Regular Expression before (see [my blog post](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/select-elements-without-a-certain-class/)), however it gets pretty messy. I would not recommended going that way.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick and subsequently resolved my other issue with selecting other cards on the screen!